# PDFScanner Automation

Tags: automator, pdf, automation, scanning

I recently purchased [PDFScanner](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/pdfscanner-simple-document/id410968114?l=en&mt=12) to convert a bunch of scans into searchable, smaller-sized PDFs. I specifically picked PDFScanner because of its AppleScript automation (see "Features" section on [PDFScanner's website](http://www.pdfscannerapp.com/#features)).

[image]

However, when I put together the above script using the built-in commands as documented in PDFScanner's AppleScript library and tried to run it, I got the following error:

[image]

At this point, I'm stuck. I've contacted the developer. He said this exact same scripts works for him and that I should try to delete and reinstall PDFScanner, which I did to no avail. Can anybody figure out what the problem is?

---

Here's the complete script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "PDFScanner"
        deskew input
        rasterize input
        ocr input
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Comment: Copy your script, paste into TextEdit, In TextEdit, go to the Format menu and choose Make Plain text. Select & copy plain text from TextEdit into workflow. Give it a whirl.

Comment: @IconDaemon Intersting idea, but the problem remains.

Comment: If 'input' is a variable you came up with, try changing it to `input_file_name` or something. Perhaps 'input' is a reserved word in Automator and can't be used as a variable..

Comment: @IconDaemon The variable `input` is in fact preconfigured when adding the "Run AppleScript" action to an Automator workflow. The following construct is added automatically: `on run {input, parameters}
 
 (* Your script goes here *)
 
 return input
end run`

Comment: Can you change it anyway and give it a test?

Comment: @IconDaemon I did right away, but to no avail.

Comment: Oh, well. Take a look at these links: [Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6503937?start=0&tstart=0) and [StackExchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197245/applescript-expected-then-but-found-identifier).

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for the links. I had found the Apple Support thread during my own searching but not the StackExchange post. Both don't seem to provide any further suggestions to my case, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the cause of the problem was trivial. I simply used the wrong type of (formatted) quotation marks in `tell application "PDFScanner"`. After removing the formatting, everything worked like a charm. This workflow saved me quite some time:

[image]

```
on run {input}

    tell application "PDFScanner"
        repeat with PDF in input
            deskew PDF
            rasterize PDF
            ocr PDF to PDF
        end repeat
    end tell

    return input
end run
```